# How to resolve version compatible error for python 3.6

Tags: python

I need to install **matplotlib** on Python 3.6.2 but when trying to install it getting this error (installing matplotlib package for designing the graphs.)The error is :-

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for install”

---

operating system is Windows 10 -64 bit.

I tried to install the package from same link shared as [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) .

but the same error appears.

I tried to install from command line plus from blue screen command `python packagename.setup` and it ended up throwing mentioned error.
it seems for python version 3.6.2 package matplotlib version 3.0.2 can not be installed because each time same error keeps populating as mentioned in previous post.

Can we use a similar other package for pie charts or graphs etc. as matplotlib version 3.0.2 is not getting installed because of mentioned error?

Comment: I formatted the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing it with "python3 -m pip install matplotlib"? Matplotlib should work with your Python version, maybe you are accidentally trying to install it for an older Python version.

Comment: As told earlier I have Python 3.6.2 installed on my machine and trying to install Matplot lib 3.0.2 version in it from the mentioned link in my previous post and then trying to setup it's giving that mentioned error. so not sure which python version i should have to successfully install this package.